# Sum of Open and Closed Set in real vector spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be subsets of a real vector space where $X$ is open and $Y$ is closed. 
Must $X+Y$ be open?

Comment: What is the relation, if any, between the sum and the topology?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for any $v$ of the space $v+X$ is open when $X$ is open, then $X+Y$ is open when $X$ is open, no matter how the set $Y$ is. Note that
$$X+Y=\bigcup_{y\in Y}(y+X)$$